# decomposing Parse NSError generated by blocks such as findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to single out the iOS error from the parse error that is generated by:

`[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {...`

When I print the [error userInfo] I get this result:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection
>   appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x7f93c5930960
>   {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f93c5e7d430 "The Internet connection appears to
>   be offline.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}

I assume the parse API adds the IOS connection NSError to the parse generated NSError. How can I retrieve the original NSError? More specifically, I want to get the NSString of the last NSLocalizedDescription, ie " The Internet connection appears to be offline."

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The original error is embedded within the `userInfo` object of the error created by Parse, with the key `originalError`. Within here, you can get the `localizedDescription` which is the value you're after.

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    NSError *originalError = error.userInfo[@"originalError"];
    NSString *description = originalError.localizedDescription;
    ...
 }
}];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. It's still not working. error.userInfo[@"originalError"] returns nil.

When trying to print:
                NSError *originalError = error.userInfo[@"originalError"];
                NSLog(@"Original Error: %@", originalError);
The output is:
Original Error: (null)

p.s. I am using it with this line:
        [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
I assume it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @user2671766 It really depends on the type of error that you're getting as to whether or not there will be an `originalError` key in the errors `userInfo`. For example, if you attempt to save a class that doesn't exist (and client class creation is turned off), you'll get a Parse 119 error with no `originalError`. If you attempt to save with no connection, you should get a Parse error 100, with an `originalError` object. You really need to test and react based on the information you have available.

Comment: I do seem to get error 100: Here is the full error. When printing:

NSLog(@"Changes not saved. Error.userInfo: %@", error.userInfo);

I get this:

Changes not saved. Error.userInfo: {
    code = 100;
    error = ... the error above.

but no 'originalError'. I tried also to use just "error" with your suggestion. It prints the "inner error",ie what printed above, but when trying to assign it to nserror and getting its userinfo it crashes.